# Instantiate Modules in Generate For Loop in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to instantiate some modules in Verilog using a `generate` block since I'm going to be instantiating a variable amount of them.

```
genvar i;
generate
    for (i=1; i<=10; i=i+1) begin
    status whatever_status (
        .clk(clk),
        .reset_n(reset_n),
        .a(a[i]),
        .b(b[i]),
        .out(out[i])
    );
end 
endgenerate
```

`a` & `b` are declared as input arrays to the parent module and `out` is declared as a array of wires.

What am I doing wrong here?  Is this not allowed in Verilog?  Quartus is telling me:

```
Error (10644): Verilog HDL error at driver.v(63): this block requires a name
```

Line 63 is the for loop above.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show `a`,`b`,`out` declaration in `status` and current module? Seems like single instance is created 10 times.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can apply label identifier to `begin`-`end` block with a colon after the begin (example: `begin : label` - `end`. This has always been an optional feature for generate blocks, though it is highly recommended.  Quartus should not be giving an error.

It is an easy fix to satisfy Quartus-- add a label of any name you want:

```
genvar i;
generate
    for (i=1; i<=10; i=i+1) begin : generate_block_identifier // <-- example block name
    status whatever_status (
        .clk(clk),
        .reset_n(reset_n),
        .a(a[i]),
        .b(b[i]),
        .out(out[i])
    );
end 
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 8):

I know this doesn't directly answer the question, but you can also declare several modules in this formation without using a `generate` block like so for 10 instances:

```
status whatever_status[9:0] (
  .clk(clk),
  .reset_n(reset_n),
  .a(a),
  .b(b),
  .out(out)
);
```

This is equivalent to the `generate` block above assuming that `a`, `b`, and `out` being passed are declared as `[9:0]`. This syntax will work as long as they're integer multiples of how they're declared in the module; they'll be spread evenly among each instance, otherwise synthesis will throw an error.

For example if `a`, `b`, and `out` are declared `[19:0]`, then every 2 bits will be passed to each instance, and it is assumed they are declared as `[1:0]` within the module `status`.

Comment: @simap thanks for the edit. I noticed the `<= 10` in the question but failed to notice the initializer was `i = 1` instead of `i = 0` (as would be typical). That was what threw me off and wrote an answer talking about 11 instances.

Answer (score 4):

Give your block a name:

```
for (i=1; i<=10; i=i+1) begin: my_status
```