# verilog expecting a semicolon error near generate block

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

It's been years I've been working with verilog but recently I'm testing something with verilog. During a ncvlog compile, I have an error for which I can't find the cause. Below is the code(not complete yet).

```
`include "default.v"

module conv (
    input clr,
    input clk,
    input start_conv,
    output integer raddr,
    output integer waddr,
    input  real data_in,
    output real data_out
);

parameter NUM_CONV = `DEF_NUM_CONV;


genvar i;
generate
for (i=0; i<NUM_CONV; i=i+1) begin : uconv
unit_conv inst() (
    .clr (clr),
    .clk (clk),
    .start (start_conv),
    .rreq (rreq[i]),
    .raddr (raddr[i]),
    .rdata (rdata[i]),
    .wreq (wreq[i]),
    .waddr (waddr[i]),
    .wdata (wdata[i])
);

end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

The error I get is like below :

```
ckim@stph45:~/Neuro/convhw] ncvlog -sv conv.v
ncvlog: 12.20-s008: (c) Copyright 1995-2013 Cadence Design Systems, Inc.
unit_conv inst() (
                 |
ncvlog: *E,EXPSMC (conv.v,19|17): expecting a semicolon (';') [12.1.2][7.1(IEEE)].
```

Is the port mapping syntax for generated instances wrong? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899691/instantiate-modules-in-generate-for-loop-in-verilog) it seems correct though... By the way, I compile with `ncvlog -SV conv.v`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
unit_conv inst (
    .clr (clr),
    .clk (clk),
    .start (start_conv),
    .rreq (rreq[i]),
    .raddr (raddr[i]),
    .rdata (rdata[i]),
    .wreq (wreq[i]),
    .waddr (waddr[i]),
    .wdata (wdata[i])
);
```

Comment: oh, I see, the () was for the port mapping.. :)